# CRUD operation for hundreds of entites (tables) in Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, crud

We have hundreds of tables in an Oracle database, one table for each entity.

Now we have to do CURD operations for the entities through our B/S application.

We use ASP.Net 4.0. It is a hard work to create `.aspx` pages for each entity.

Any suggestions?

> You could use a code generation tool that support Oracle, such as this
>   product: softfluent.com/products/codefluent-entities (free for
>   personal use)

It seems that this will generate the static forms for each entity, then how about if the table changed (like add/remove field)?

Comment: You may create a utility that create the pages :)

Comment: You could use a code generation tool that support Oracle, such as this product: http://www.softfluent.com/products/codefluent-entities (free for personal use)

Comment: @hguser - For a tool like that you would need to regenerate. You want a site that's completely automatic and supports database schema change without recompiling?

Comment: @SimonMourier: It would be better if it can be implemented.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand the situation, but it may make sense to put CRUD operations in either a middleware/WCF service or even in the database layer.  Also, since it seems you're just starting this project, have you considered asp mvc?

Comment: Try Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html It includes ASP.NET web pages generator and other useful tools for your task.

Comment: @ThinkJet: I have tried the ODT, it is wonderful. But we want take control of the represent for  some fields. Most of them are rendered as a TextBox, how about we need some DropDownList?

Comment: @hguser Sorry, I didn't explore capabilites of ODT in details, just suppose it as probably useful tool for your purposes. You can ask questions about ODT here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=228 or create just another question on StackOverflow ...

Comment: Are the entities truly independent to the point that can't be combined into tables sharing a lot of common fields?

Comment: In fact, the entities have lots of common fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes

you have code generators

https://www.google.co.il/search?q=crud+code+generator+asp+net&rlz=1C1CHEU_iwIL514IL514&oq=crud+code+generator+asp+net&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5881j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

https://www.google.co.il/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHEU_iwIL514IL514&biw=1536&bih=783&q=related:www.hkvstore.com/aspnetmaker/+aspx+maker&tbo=1

this is a simple process that you do you generate the app, and you do only the custom pages.
this way you generate back-end quickly.

Comment: It does not support oracle.

Comment: you can search one that supports (add oracle to search term)

Answer (score 2):

Use Visual Studio 2010/2012 to create an EDMX for Entity Framework from the existing database. Then you will have a model.

After that, you can use ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET and use Scaffolding: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-dynamic-data/your-first-scaffold-and-what-is-dynamic-data

The pages wont be super pretty, but it works.

If the Entity Framework will not auto generate, I would check out www.devart.com they have a lot of .NET to Oracle tools which could help.

Comment: this is also a possibility "Dynamic Data" +  "Entity Framework"

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20Data&referringTitle=Home

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: i had projects with dynamic data and with phpmaker.
i feel that the professional code generators are much quicker to get a good result then Dynamic Data framework.